# Extrair Vencimento Linha Digitável

Tags: delphi

Tenho a seguinte linha digitável de um boleto, preciso de uma função para extrair a data de vencimento dela, e posteriormente usar em outras.

> Linha Digitável:  74893.12004.21627.007186.37931.981056 1 59490000041480

Sei que o `5949` é o vencimento do boleto, mas não consigo converter para uma Data. Montei a seguinte função mais não funcionou:

```pascal
function ExtrairDataVencimento(const CodigoBarras: String): TDateTime;
begin
Result := StrToDate('07/10/1997') + StrToInt(Copy(CodigoBarras, 34, 4));
WriteLn(Result);
end;
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Só pra constar - formato da linha digitável: `bbbmL.LLLLLd LLLLL.LLLLLd LLLLL.LLLLLd D FFFFVVVVVVVVVV`, sendo `b`=banco / `m`=moeda (9=real) / `L`="Campo livre" / `d`=Dígito verificador do bloco / `D`=Dígito verificador da linha / `F` = Fator de Vencimento (dias com base em 7 de Outubro de 1997) / `V` = Valor * 100. - O "Campo livre" possui dados como número de convênio, agência, ou outros parâmetros, e varia de banco pra banco.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja se é isso que você procura:

```pascal
const
CodigoDeBarras: string = '74893.12004.21627.007186.37931.981056 1 59490000041480';

function ExtrairDataVencimento(const CodigoBarras: String): TDateTime;
begin
Result := StrToDate('07/10/1997') + StrToInt(Copy(CodigoBarras, 41, 4)); // 5949
ShowMessage(DateToStr(Result));
end;
```

Se você estiver construindo um aplicativo console:

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
CodigoDeBarras: string = '74893.12004.21627.007186.37931.981056 1 59490000041480';

function ExtrairDataVencimento(const CodigoBarras: String): TDateTime;
begin
Result := StrToDate('07/10/1997') + StrToInt(Copy(CodigoBarras, 41, 4));
Writeln(DateToStr(Result));
end;

begin
ExtrairDataVencimento(CodigoDeBarras);
Readln;
end.
```

A função [`DateToStr()`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=DateToStr) converte um valor do tipo[DataTime](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TDateTime) em uma string formatada.

Comment: você me salvando de novo rsrsrs. Cara, quase deu certo, mais ele mostrou a data errada. O boleto venceu dia 20/01/2014, ele mostrou no show 25/04/2013.

Comment: sim, pode entrar nesse site e colar ele: http://evandro.net/codigo_barras.html

Comment: Voces estao usando data errada. A base correta do fator de vencimento é 07 de Outubro de 1997

Comment: @Bacco, perfeito a sua resposta, era isso mesmo. Com o código do DBX8 e sua resposta deu certinho. Obrigado!