# Converter fator de vencimento (número de dias) de boleto em data dd/mm/aaaa

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte linha digitável:

```
74893.12004 21627.007186 37931.981056 7 60750000001400
```

Como já visto nesta pergunta, descobri como calcular o vencimento matematicamente:

[Extrair Vencimento Linha Digitável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17303/extrair-vencimento-linha-digitavel)

Preciso do equivalente em JS, que é extrair o fator de vencimento (quatro primeiros caracteres do último bloco, no exemplo acima 6075), e somar este número à data 7/10/1997 (a data 7 de Outubro de 1997 é sempre esta, base de todos os boletos padrão Febraban), obtendo o vencimento no formato dd/mm/aaaa.

Exemplo: para o fator 1001 a data resultante tem que ser 4/07/2000.

Comment: você já conseguiu extrair apenas o campo relativo ao código do vencimento?

Comment: @Bacco, a outra pergunta era pra Delphi, como faço isso no java ?

Comment: @user7605 você quer java ou javascript?

Comment: @Erlon, já sim usei o: teste.substr(40,4);

Comment: @ErlonCharles, JAVASCRIPT..

Comment: @Bacco posta aí como comentário o link da outra pergunta

Comment: Ok @Bacco, obrigado pela atenção. Lembrando que preciso converter esse código que consta o VENCIMENTO em data de vencimento correto  no estilo xx/xx/xxxx ok ?

Comment: @ErlonCharles, em delphi ficaria assim: Result := StrToDate('07/10/1997') + StrToInt(Copy(CodigoBarras, 41, 4)); Agora queria fazer em JAVASCRIPT..

Comment: Ótimo @Bacco, obrigado!

Comment: Boa pergunta, não sabia que isso era possível :) `+1`

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco....

Comment: Vejam também este link: http://boletobancario-codigodebarras.blogspot.com.br/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Veja se isso funciona para você:

```
var barra = "74893.12004 21627.007186 37931.981056 7 60750000001400";
var vencimento = barra.slice(40, 44); // captura 6075 
var date = new Date('10/07/1997');
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (vencimento * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

alert(("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear());
```

Ou utilizando como fator o número *1001*:

```
var barra = "74893.12004 21627.007186 37931.981056 7 60750000001400";
var vencimento = 1001;
var date = new Date('10/07/1997');
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (vencimento * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

alert(("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear());
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jf6Lz/)

Como bem apontado pelo @Bernardo Botelho, o código acima provavelmente irá retornar o dia incorreto se estivermos em [horário de verão](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver%C3%A3o), uma forma para detectar isso em JavaScript é descrito [nesse artigo](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldst.htm)(*em inglês*).

Comment: só tem um problema, ficou perfeito seu código, mais preciso que ele aparece os 0 no vencimento, por exemplo, 26/07/2014, ele aparece 26/7/2014 o "7" sem o "0" antes, entendeu ? da pra arrumar isso ?

Comment: Tá show esse stackOverflow brasileiro hein...:)

Comment: @Sunstreaker, ele ainda não mostra os "0" ZEROS no vencimento.

Comment: O problema de utilizar horas é que alguns dias não tem 24 horas, devido ao horário de verão. Se uma data de vencimento cair nesse dia, você terá o dia incorreto.

Comment: Creio que somando umas 5 horas na fórmula resolveria esse problema. (ou subtraindo, não analisei se a referência é 0h00 ou 24h00)

Comment: Entendi.....farei esse teste, mais como eu faço para ele não eliminar os zeros ? ele ta mostrando assim 3/6/2014, o correto seria 03/06/2014.

Comment: @Sunstreaker, quase perfeito, o problema que ele está adicionando mais um dia no vencimento...só isso, os zeros apareceram. Se o boleto venceu ontem 28/05/2014, ele está mostrando 29/05/2014.

Comment: @Sunstreaker, já resolvi, só troquei o date.getDate() + 1) pelo date.getDate() + 0). Obrigado.

Comment: O erro acontece na próxima data do horário de verão brasileiro: 18/10/2014. Ao somar horas você cai na meia noite do dia 18. Como é nesse dia que o horário de verão começa, o horário é ajustado para 17/10/2014, às 23:00 horas. Todos os boletos que caírem no dia 18 terão a data modificada para dia 17, incorretamente. Veja o JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzxbot/mejDr/ . O problema pode ser observado no Chrome e no Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Adicionando um método à classe Date:

```
var linhaDigitavel = "74893.12004 21627.007186 37931.981056 7 60750000001400";

var dias = parseInt(linhaDigitavel.substr(40, 4));

Date.prototype.adicionarDias = function(dias) {
    var data = new Date(this.valueOf());
    data.setDate(data.getDate() + dias);
    return data;
};

// Meses são indexados em zero em JavaScript, logo é necessário subtrair 1 do mês desejado.
var dataInicialFebraban = new Date(1997, 10 - 1, 7);

alert(dataInicialFebraban);

alert(dataInicialFebraban.adicionarDias(dias));

// Resultado: 26/05/2014
```

Link para o JSFiddle utilizado: http://jsfiddle.net/bzxbot/YEaLR/

Como referência, vou deixar uma solução que **NÃO** deve ser utilizada:

```
var dias = 6075;
var inicio = new Date(1997, 10 - 1, 7);
var vencimento = new Date();
vencimento.setDate(today.getDate() + dias);
alert(vencimento);
// Resultado (incorreto): 24/12/2030
```

JSFiddle do exemplo incorreto: http://jsfiddle.net/bzxbot/xTD6s/

Referência para mesma pergunta no Stack Overflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime

Comment: Se quiser, pode atualizar sua observação. Eu digitei errado na pergunta, o mês correto é 7 e não 6 como eu tinha posto antes, mas já corrigi a pergunta ;) De fato o resultado tem que ser 04/07/2000, conforme obtido nos seus testes.

Comment: Certo, removi a observação.